# Pattern match for a Switch Case statement in Groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm trying to match the cases where the attribute "fromNamePath" contains "CASE_N", the attributte string has the following structure:

```
"State/Fields/CASE_N"
```

I've tried:

```
case ~/CASE_N/:

case ~"CASE_N":

case ~/\w+CASE_N/:
```

This is the switch:

```
switch(mapping.getAttribute("fromNamePath").getValue()) {
                case ~/\w+CASE_N/:
                    logger.info("Found CASE_N");
                default:
                    logger.info(mapping.getAttribute("fromNamePath").getValue());
}
```

This is the dataset that logs:

```
State/Fields/DAY
State/Fields/FROM
State/Fields/CASE_N
```

I'm getting all the values logged from the default case instead of what I expected:

```
State/Fields/DAY
State/Fields/FROM
Found CASE_N
```

Comment: `\w+` includes only letters, but you have '/' in the input string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\w+` includes only letters, but you have '/' in the input string

this works fine:

```
switch("State/Fields/CASE_N"){
    case ~/[\w\/]+CASE_N$/:
        println "case 1"
        break
    default:
        println "default"
        break
}
```